# Customizing newlistof{Floats}

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, lists

Im building a custom list for "boxes" (or closed tables). Note they can't be named as table.

The only way to to add boxes as a environment was over the Floats. Any tip here could help. Something like \begin{table1} \begin{table2}

Almost everything is ok after time spent in researching, but i need custom it a little bit more.

Here is how my list of boxes (Quadros) is now: 
[image]

And this one is the original "LOF", how mine must look like
[image]

The main problem is add "**BOX**" 1 "**–**" First Box Float ...... 3", like is shown in \listoffigures

My actual code is:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
oneside,
brazil           
]{abntex2}          

% ---------- PACOTES -----------------------------------------------

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{times}          
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{float}          
\usepackage{babel}  
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}  % alinhamento do titulo da  tabela   


\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}

% ---------- DECLARING FLOAT 1 -----------------------------------

    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{tocloft}


        \newcommand{\quadroname}{Quadro}
        \newcounter{quadroname}

        \floatstyle{plaintop}
        \newfloat{Quadro}{hbtp}{loq}
        \newlistof{listofquadros}{loq}{\listofquadrosname}

%   - Ajuste do Float       
        \setfloatadjustment{Quadro}{\centering}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}


%   - Cria a lista
        \newcommand{\listofquadrosname}{Lista de Quadros}



%   - Configurações adicionais  
!!!! ((((( IF I USE THIS BLOCK IT WILL LOOK EXACTLY LIKE FIGURE (  FIGURE 1 - First Box Float )

%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\listof}[2]{
%   \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
%       \expandafter\let\csname l@#1\endcsname \l@figure
%       \float@listhead{#2}%
%       \begingroup
%       \setlength\parskip{0pt plus 1pt}%               
%       \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
%       \endgroup}}
%\makeatother



% ---------- INICIO DO DOCUMENTO ------------------------------------

\begin{document}


% ---------- LISTS --------------------------------------------------


    \pdfbookmark[0]{\listofquadrosname}{s}
    \listof{quadro}{Lista de Quadros}
    \cleardoublepage


    \listoffigures
    \cleardoublepage


% ---------- QUADROS ------------------------------------------------


Any text refering to  \autoref{quad:ex1}

\begin{quadro}
    \caption{First Box Float}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        text1   & text3 & text5   \\ \hline
        text2   & text4 & text6   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{quad:ex1}
\end{quadro}



\begin{quadro}
    \caption{Second Box Float}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        text1   & text3 & text5   \\ \hline
        text2   & text4 & text6   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{quad:ex2}
\end{quadro}


Text linking to \autoref{quad:ex3}


\begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \centering
    \caption{The first figure}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{quad:ex3}
    \legend{Fonte: O autor}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `abntex2` is based on `memoir`, you should use this class's methods.

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  oneside,
  brazil           
]{abntex2}          

% ---------- PACOTES -----------------------------------------------

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{times}          
\usepackage{babel}  
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}  % alinhamento do titulo da  tabela   


\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}

% ---------- DECLARING FLOAT 1 -----------------------------------

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\quadroname}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\listofquadrosname}{Lista de Quadros}

\newfloat{quadro}{loq}{\quadroname}
\setfloatadjustment{quadro}{\centering}
\newlistof{listofquadros}{loq}{\listofquadrosname}
\newlistentry{quadro}{loq}{0}
\renewcommand{\cftquadroname}{\quadroname\space} 
\renewcommand{\cftquadroaftersnum}{\hfill\textendash\hfill}


% ---------- INICIO DO DOCUMENTO ------------------------------------

\begin{document}


% ---------- LISTS --------------------------------------------------


\pdfbookmark[0]{\listofquadrosname}{s}
\listofquadros
\cleardoublepage


\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage


% ---------- QUADROS ------------------------------------------------


Any text refering to  \autoref{quad:ex1}

\begin{quadro}
    \caption{First Box Float}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        text1   & text3 & text5   \\ \hline
        text2   & text4 & text6   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{quad:ex1}
\end{quadro}



\begin{quadro}
    \caption{Second Box Float}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        text1   & text3 & text5   \\ \hline
        text2   & text4 & text6   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{quad:ex2}
\end{quadro}


Text linking to \autoref{quad:ex3}


\begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \centering
    \caption{The first figure}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
        \hline \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{quad:ex3}
    \legend{Fonte: O autor}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's great. I've tried something close to this, but is failed. Thank you @egreg